# Evaluate (run, process) HTML/SVG with embedded JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom

How can Node.js (or any other engine) "run" (process, evaluate) HTML or SVG files with embedded JavaScript (that modifies the DOM) and output the resulting document?

Comment: By providing a runtime environment for script portions (JavaScript VM), implementing the relevant APIs that may be accessed from the html / svg document (foremost the DOM API) and - if the 'resulting document' is meant to be a graphical representation - by providing a rendering engine similar to that of a browser. Of course none of the components need to support all features known from common user agent.

Comment: If you want to play with DOM API on NodeJS or simillar, I suggest `jsdom`

Comment: `jsdom` does not seem to support SVG, running `$ chromium --headless --disable-gpu --dump-dom "file:///path/to/local/file.svg" produces an empty HTML document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't.
A JavaScript engine by itself has no notion of the HTML or SVG DOM.
It would need additional libraries (see comments).

The alternative is to use a Browser to evaluate the file without rendering it ("headless" mode).